# android spinner setText removes other elements that not contain this text- BUG

Tags: android, frame

I'm adding a set of spinners dynamically from the code,
to a user control - frame layout type (using data binding to set the values from a view model), 
this is the function to inflate the layout(I call it from the Ctor):

```
   private void initInflate() {

        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        binding = SensorSettingsBinding.inflate(inflater, this, true);
        binding.linear.setDividerPadding(10);

        for (SensorSettingViewModel s :Settings) {
            MaterialBetterSpinner spinner = new MaterialBetterSpinner(getContext());
            spinner.setHint(s.getSettingName());
            spinner.setHintTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorHint));
            spinner.setMinimumWidth(100);
            spinner.setFloatingLabelTextSize(40);
            spinner.setTextSize(15);
            spinner.setFloatingLabel(MaterialAutoCompleteTextView.FLOATING_LABEL_HIGHLIGHT);
            spinner.setFloatingLabelText(s.getSettingName());
            spinner.setId(s.getId());
            ArrayAdapter<String> spinnerArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getContext(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, s.getValues());
            spinner.setAdapter(spinnerArrayAdapter);
            spinner.setText(spinnerArrayAdapter.getItem(s.getIndex()));
//            spinner.setSelection(s.getIndex());
            binding.linear.addView(spinner);

            MarginLayoutParams params = (ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams)spinner.getLayoutParams();
            params.setMargins(30, 0, 30, 0); //substitute parameters for left, top, right, bottom
            spinner.setLayoutParams(params);
        }
    }
```

I tried to select a specific index from the  spinner values:

```
spinner.setSelection(s.getIndex());
```

but it didn't work, I found a solution for this (in stack overflow):

```
spinner.setText(spinnerArrayAdapter.getItem(s.getIndex()));
```

this is selecting a value from spinner by a string value item.
but here I have a really strange bug: **all the values of the spinner are getting clear** and only the values that contains this string are staying in spinner list.

another issue is that this caused , the **color material design** of this spinner disapears
any ideas??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem by me was solve this way:
i put the set to the index befor the setAdapter:

```
spinner.setText(spinnerArrayAdapter.getItem(s.getIndex()));     
spinner.setAdapter(spinnerArrayAdapter);
```

but i still think that this is a bug in android..
anyway the other problem about the material design color is not related to this change..